# two click handler on same element conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element `#div_1` which has inside the same document (not extern file) a plain JS function:

```
var trigger = false;
var div_1 = document.getElementById('div_1')
div_1.onclick = function() { trigger = true; };
```

and in an extern JS file I have a jQuery button click on the same element:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#div_1').click(function() {
   // some actions here
 });
});
```

The problem is that it does ignore the jQuery clickhandler completely. Is there no way to have two seperate click handler which work both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something else going on in your code because you can certainly have multiple event handlers on an object.

You can only have one handler assigned via `onclick`, but that should, in no way, interfere with the jQuery event handler.  Please show us a reproducible demo in a jsFiddle because there is likely some other problem with your code causing this.

FYI, I'd strong suggest you not use the `onclick` attribute for event handlers because there is danger of one event handler overwriting another, something that does not happen when using `.addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.click()`.  But, neither `.addEventListener()` or jQuery's `.click()` will overwrite the `onlick`.

Here's a working demo that shows both event handlers working just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4Ge52/

Comment: first thank you for your suggestion, and then I have to say that I don't have a clou what is wrong. I don't get an errormessage or something similar.

Comment: @supersize - you must have inadvertently fixed some other error then because I just added a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4Ge52/) that shows your original code working just fine.

Comment: I really don't know why, but the `.addEventListener()` works, the `.onclick` does not. But I see your working fiddle and that means I must have something in my code what interacts with the `onclick`. Anyway your post was very helpful and solved my problem! Thank you for that!